# Sitecore 10.2 CLI error the SSL connection could not be established

Tags: sitecore-cli

While I have setup the CLI in helix project root folder and trying to run below command I'm getting error

> dotnet sitecore ser pull

The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Does your CM URL work in browser without SSL errors? https://<cm>/sitecore/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `https://` in your instance. Add `https://` in your instance name in `user.json (\.sitecore\user.json)` and then try again.

```
"host": "https://sc10sc.dev.local",
"authority": "https://sc10identityserver.dev.local"
```

Comment: Yes in user.json file the host and authority has https, but still same error, i check event log there is showing A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013. but I'm not sure this is the inner exception or not

Answer (score 0):

The above issue was untrusted certificate , so the certificate named  $SitecoreSiteName.pfx need to move under trusted root certificate folder, this solved my issue.