Sitecore 10.3 Content Serialization CLI SSL Errors
I am trying to setup content serialization for a Sitecore 10.3 site. I'm working with a Hyper-V VM where I created the sites. I'm able to load the CM and identity server in a browser but am unable to login through command line and the CLI in order to setup/configure the rest of the content serialization.
The error I’m receiving is as follows:
Logging in to Sitecore. You should see a browser window open shortly.
Error connecting to (site removed for security reasons).well-known/openid-configuration: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

When executing dotnet Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.dll from the identity server on my host machine I receive the error below.

However when I run the same command from within the VM itself (from the identity server) I get the output below.

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Does this answer your question? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31593/sitecore-10-2-cli-error-the-ssl-connection-could-not-be-established. Can you find and post the inner exception?

I've tried modifying the user.json file as mentioned in that post. I have no tried changing the certificate because I don't fully understand how to do that.

I've also looked at the logs under the identity server but don't seem to see the inner exception anywhere.

@BenDallman Can you try running command dotnet Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.dll directly from the identity server and check for any error..

And also can you confirm is this url https://{{IdentityServerHosy}}/.well-known/openid-configuration returning a valid json..

You can check this link for the certificate issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/sdn/articles/installing-the-trusted-root-certificate

@ckhanna it is returning a valid json. I can hit the identity server in the browser as well and it loads the login screen.

@ckhanna I get an error if I run that command from my host but when I run it from within the VM itself it appears to be fine. I'll put a screenshot of the output of both above in the original post.

You can run the below command from the identity server and check for any errors.
dotnet Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.dll

From the current error you shared, it looks the certificate thumbprint is not valid Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml inside the identity server.
You can get the certicate thumbprint on your machine by running below command.
Get-ChildItem -path Cert:localmachine\My

Based on your identity server name you can get the value of certificate thumbprint and update on the above file. Once the changes are done you can restart the identity server.
Update:
It might be the case that the certificate you are using for identity server is not trusted. You can copy the certificate from the personal certificate to the trusted certificate folder. In order to do the same, you can search for Manage User Certificates from the search panel, and then find the identity server certificate in the personal folder and copy the same to trusted root certificate folder.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

I checked the certificate thumbprint by running that command and verified it is what is currently in the Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml file.

@BenDallman Can you try copying the certificate from personal to trusted root certificate folder and thereafter restart identity server. I have updated the answer above. Let me know in case you have any queries.

Copying the cert from the personal to trusted root certificate folder did not have any effect.

@BenDallman is it possible to connect over Sitecore slack?
